# No response on clicking IONIC select box on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

On Clicking Select Box on Ionic SELECT, it returns nothing on the interface although the option values exist.

I read around and I found out it was a bug on IONIC when IONIC automatically removes the 300ms delay in order to make Ionic apps feel more “native” like.

This only happens on Android OS .

There is another question posted about this.

[How can I get Ionic select box working on Android again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642248/how-can-i-get-ionic-select-box-working-on-android-again)

[image: Screenshot on Selecting IONIC Select Box on Android]

It is shown that upon clicked, there is no response to show the option list.

```
<div class="list">
     <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Username</span>  

      <div class="input-label ng-binding"> TESXX</div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </label>


     <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Balance</span>  

      <div class="input-label ng-binding">   1,200,100 </div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </label>    
     <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Direction</span>  
     <select ng-model="formData6.dir" name="dir" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
  <option ng-selected="1" value="0" selected="selected">From</option>
  <option value="1">To</option>
     </select>          
    </label>
   </div>
```

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/get-selected-value-from-a-select/20241/8

Comment: @AnujGupta HI Gupta. this is not about getting selected value of the select box but select box response from a tap action.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still using Ionic 1, the solution to this is to allow browser's default behavior on taping a select (in Ionic 1.2.4 this was found at line 3060).